# Reference Request: On the proof of $H(x)$ sets in ZF?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Who was the first to prove that for every set $X$, there exists a set of all sets hereditarily strictly subnumerous to $X$, in ZF alone (i.e.; without choice)?

Where $S$ is hereditarily strictly subnumerous to $|X|$ means that: $$\forall s \in \text {trcl}(\{S\})(|s| < |X|)$$; where $|Y|$ is the Scott's cardinality of $Y$; and $$\text {trcl}(S)= \bigcup\big{\{}S, \ \bigcup S \ , \ \bigcup\bigcup S  \ , \bigcup \bigcup\bigcup S, ... \big{\}}$$

Comment: I am not familiar with *this* definition of $H(x)$ in the ZF context. This would make the third definition that I've seen in the last six months (the other two being the one David Aspero and I gave in our paper, and Gabe Goldberg gave one more focused on large cardinal properties in one of his recent papers). So asking for historical reference is kind of moot here. The real question is who defined it like that?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I'm familiar with Randall Holmes's definition, where he actually gave a proof of this result. (although he writes it as $H(|X|)$. Also I believe that Thomas Jech have made it for the countable case. I'm not sure of Forster's work, but Randall Holmes alluded to it in his article. But Holmes himself doesn't know if it he was the first to prove this result? Hence my question. See Randall Holmes's home page.

Comment: Where did Jech use this definition? Randall should be able to answer, and if not, Thomas Forster is always just an email away.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, this is Randall Holmes own proof, which is the only one I know of, see references in which Forsters article is there, its actually free online. https://randall-holmes.github.io/Drafts/hereditary.pdf

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I've actually spotted a trivial error in the proof of Randall Holmes, but its remediable easily, actually I've made a write up on this  subject.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, About Jech I think in his article on herediarily countable sets, unfortunately I don't have it now. Mind you that Forster's proof is in NF, but Holmes says its convertable easily to ZF milieu, and its restricted to the case of well ordered sets. But Holmes's proof is the most general one.

Comment: I am not sure this is what you want, but I found a relevant paper: Rathjen, Michael, and Robert S. Lubarsky. "On the regular extension axiom and its variants." *Mathematical Logic Quarterly* 49.5 (2003): 511-518.